# How to ignore 'Rendering Problems' in android studio layout preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have some views that couldn't be instantiated, which is really annoying:

[image: Rendering Problems]

How could I resolve this issue? or even just ignore if there is no way to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new library try to rebuild the project and then refesh the layout preview.

Comment: Try adjust with your current API Level. In the Android button of the image, now you have in API 25.

Answer (score 0):

Change your api level appropriate your Sdk

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

here where is red Circle.

[image]

for example: if your sdk version is 24 set it to 24..

Comment: my sdk version is 25

Comment: try to do it 24